# Access SharePoint Web Services at runtime

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to make a program that creates folder structures in Sharepoint from CRM (i.e. the code runs from Microsoft CRM 2011).  However, one of my goals is for the code to dynamically access multiple sharepoint sites by inputting a different URL.

The idea is that, given a sharepoint URL and appropriate credentials, the code will still be able to interact with the Sharepoint Site.  However, I am trying to avoid adding service references for every Sharepoint Site (potentially including sites yet to be created).

So, I'm wondering, is it possible to have this access to Sharepoint with only URL and credentials provided at runtime or will I need to create individual service references every time a new SP site is set up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic web service references.

Have a look at 
    http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12317/How-to-make-your-Web-Reference-proxy-URL-dynamic

If you are using SharePoint Client Object API you can set the url and password dynamically. Configure the url and password in your app.config file.

```
using (ClientContext clientcontext = new ClientContext("http://yourspserverurl/")) {
      clientcontext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
      List list = clientcontext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("your sharepoint list");
      clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();

}
```

For SharePoint 2013

`Please see my blog`https://mydevexperience.wordpress.com/2013/10/20/sharepoint-2013-office-365-authentication-using-sharepoint-client-object-model/